# Angularjs factory http get gives 'undefined is not a function'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

Here is my code. I get an error that says: `TypeError: undefined is not a function`:
I think the issue is my lack of understanding of promises, but if someone could enlighten me, I'd greatly appreciate it.

```
getProgramDetails:  function (program) {
    var _this = this;
    this.getDetails(program).then(function() {
        ....
    });
},
getDetails: function (program) {
    var _this = this;
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    // Error occurs at this line
    this.http.get({id: program.programID}).then(function(results) {
        if (results && results.programID) {
            _this.isNewProgram = false;
            _this.selectedProgram = {
                ...
            };
        } else {
            _this.isNewProgram = true;
            _this.selectedProgram = {
                ...
            };
        }
        deferred.resolve();
    });
    return deferred.promise;
},

http: $resource(
$window.detailsEndpoint',
{ id: '@id' },
{   //parameters default
    update: {
        method: 'PUT',
        params: {}
    },
    get: {
        method: 'GET',
        params: {
            id: '@id'
        }
    },
    post: {
        method: 'POST'
    }
})
```

Comment: If you could give us a little more information that would be helpful!

Comment: `$window.detailsEndpoint'` appears to be missing a `'`

Comment: What more info do you need? I've already been given, implemented and accepted the correct answer. The ' was a typo. The person giving the correct answer clearly understood that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `$resource` has a `.then()` method like `$http` instead try pass the callback as the second argument

```
this.http.get({id: program.programID}, function(results){});
```

Or call its `$promise`

```
this.http.get({id: program.programID}).$promise.then(function(results){});
```

Comment: Thanks much! I chose the first option.